# What is the right way to fetch data that is being automatically posted to the URL that I'm developing the app on in Django?

Tags: python, json, django, python-requests, fetch

There is data being automatically sent with POST request to the address I'm developing on, in format of JSON string.

How should I properly fetch this data in my function based view, so I can manipulate with it?
`data = requests.get(url).json()` did not work for me, it gives me back this error:
`django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLResolver <URLResolver list> (None:None) 'en/'>]], 'path': ''}`

At least, how can I test if there is any data being sent to the url?
I'm developing in production env.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the data is posted you will be able to find the data with

> request.POST.get('url')

or if it is not sent as JSON body it will be found within, which will need to be decoded manually

> request.body